# Visual Studio Code horizontal and vertical split

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have set up my Sublime Text editor as follows:

[image]

I have done it using `View > Groups > Max Columns: 2`

I am trying to replicate it in Visual Studio Code, but could not find any options for that.

I am using Visual Studio Code version 1.21 in Ubuntu 16.04.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you can't. There is a request for that feature on vscode github. see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9443) for yourself

Comment: You can at least say how much you miss it over there. You never know :)

Answer (score 7):

In current VS Code¹ you can find different window groupings and layouts in the following menu:

- `View > Editor Layout`

To make a new horizontal split (two editors stacked on top of each other), select `Split Down`, or the preset `Two Rows`.

[image: Screenshot of VS Code Menu]

---

Footnote:

> 1: Grid layouts were added in [May 2018 version 1.24](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_editor-grid-layout)

Answer (score 4):

"Toggle editor group layout"
You can also toggle between horizontal or vertical split layouts in VS Code. To do so, you use the toggle editor group command from View. then  spilt editor command.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode 1.77 (March 2023) offers a new contextual menu directly on the empty editor tabs space, from which you can trigger an horizontal or vertical split:

See [issue 175667](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175667) and [commit e7157fe](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/e7157fe5727ef844ab7b17cd115afddbbc7eefe2), available in [VSCode insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/900690/221912202-80089fae-3045-4948-af49-2cf717b1f478.gif]

Answer (score 0):

right-click on the top of the terminal window (where you have the PROBLEM OUTPUT TERMINAL ...) and select 'move panel to right' or 'move panel to left' if you prefer the left side.